# insert multiple ID in mysql row

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert multiple data in a single mysql row?

Example of multiple id:

41,32,31,293,877

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea

Comment: What is a "MySQL raw"?

Comment: @OP: *raw* or *row* ???

Comment: Must be some spelling or accent typo. corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare column to be VARCHAR().
yes you can insert multiple IDs.  like

```
INSERT INTO table (Id) value ('41,32,31,293,877');
```

Comment: Note that this is very bad database design. It will create problems later that are hard to work around. It is better to use an extra table to store the relations.

Comment: Yes, note that actually *doing* this means that the table fails to be First Normal Form.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to insert the multiple values at a time in mysql database.

suppose you have created a table of name `emp`. and in this table you have 1 field which is named as `id`.

now you just want to insert the multiple `id` in a table named `emp` , so can do this by writing following command ->

```
INSERT INTO emp(id) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

Above query will insert the following given values in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting into a single table, you can write your query like this :

```
 insert into table (id) values (41),(32),(31),(293),(877);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using varchar or text data type for Id field then it is possible to enter and store with comma separated.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Id) VALUES ('41,32,31,293,877');
```